# To find combination of a list

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm implementing Apriori algorithm. and i need to calculate the combination of a list 
for example i have a list containing 
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
and its out put should be like this
ABCDEF
ABCGHI
ABCJKL

plz tell me that hw i can get the output like this.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Simple approach

```
var inputs = new [] { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO" };
var combi = from first in inputs
            from second in inputs
            select first+second;
```

Flexible approach (published by [Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/))

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) =>  
      from accseq in accumulator  
      from item in sequence  
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item}));                
}
```

Use it like

```
var combi = new [] { inputs, inputs }.CartesianProduct();
```

The power comes from being able to do

```
var combi = new [] { inputs, inputs, somethingelse, inputs }.CartesianProduct();
```

just as easily